# How to change the display of an axis Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, display

I want to change only the values shown on the x-axis, but not the values of the dataset,which can be seen by hovering on the curve. I've tried:

```
callback: function(value) {return Math.round(value);}
```

in the `xAxes` `ticks`, but it also changes the dataset.
Is there any way to only change the display?

Here is my curve:
[curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMl2c.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the options for to xAxes of your chart.

```
const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',
data: data,
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                callback: function(value, index, values) {
                    return Math.round(value).toString();
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
               return data.labels[tooltipItem[0].index];
          }
       }
   }
}});
```

I think that this won't change the dataset.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, but that's exactly what I did, and it didn't work.

Comment: Ahhh sorry i edit the answer so you need to overwrite the callback for tooltips also.

Comment: Thank you, this is working! The return of the tooltip callback should be `return data.labels[tooltipItem[0].index]` though. Thanks!